# How to quickly refresh images on screen with Python/OS-X and improve upon opencv's imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, pyglet, pyopengl

I'm working on a Python (2.7.13) program that reads images from the webcam (refreshed on a separate thread), does a perspective transform, and puts the live video in a window on the screen, using opencv (3.2.0-dev).  I get very low FPS (13) updating a 720x1280 output image with cv2.imshow().  If I remove the call to cv2.imshow() and keep the rest of the loop the same, it goes up to 75 FPS.  What should I use in place of cv2.imshow() to get a reduce this image refresh bottleneck?  I'm using a 2016 MacBook Pro with dedicated graphics card.

Do I need PyOpenGL for this, and if so are there any clear examples documented?  I tried Pygame's blit function and did not see an improvement in FPS.  I considered Pyglet which uses OpenGL, but I was not familiar with the paradigm of events used by Pyglet, and wasn't ready to rewrite my code if it turns out there's a more appropriate way to do it, as Pyglet seems to be mainly for games and some sources say it's not well maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imshow()` feature is not really intended for real-time or streaming video display.  You can easily run at frame rate using OpenGL, but there's quite a bit of effort involved. Have a look at [PySDL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySDL2/0.2.0) which gives you a higher level API to OpenGL but is still designed for frame rate performance.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  The answer to this question has code that could be adapted: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434348/converting-cv2-images-to-pysdl2-surfaces-for-blitting-to-screen#19554202)

Answer (score 0):

Try showing only every n-th image.

Or try saving the image to disk- preferably ssd or ramdisk - and show it with an imageviewer that supports auto- reloading.

You will not see all images this way, but most probably it's enough for monitoring- and you save the precious calculation time from openCV.